# Message queque mq send error. Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, client-server, message-queue

I am trying to write to my message queue (mq_send).

Here is my code for opening the queue first and then for writing to it.

Opening:

```
int MQconnect (mqd_t * mq, char * name)
{
    //printf("hello from MQconnect\n");
    do{
        mq=mq_open(name, O_WRONLY);  //O_RDONLY
    }while(mq==-1);

    if(mq== -1){
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return 1;
    // Connects to an existing mailslot for writing Uses mq as reference pointer, so that you can     reach the handle from anywhere/
    // Should return 1 on success and 0 on fail*/
}
```

Writing:

```
int MQwrite (mqd_t mq, void * sendBuffer) // (const char) sendBuffer
{
    int nrOfBytes = mq_send(mq, (const char)sendBuffer, 1024, 10);

    printf("\n%d", nrOfBytes);

    return nrOfBytes; //nrOfBytes;

    // Write a msg to a mailslot, return nr Uses mq as reference pointer, so that you can reach the handle from anywhere
    // should return number of bytes read         */
}
```

The opening works fine but I cant write to the message queue.

mq_send return -1 as return value and the error message is:

Value of errno: 9
Error printed by perror: Bad file descriptor
Error: Bad file descriptor

The call to the above functions happens from this function:

```
void * mqClient(void * arg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    char answer[20];
    mqd_t mq_on_server;
    usleep(1000);
    int response = MQconnect(&mq_on_server, "/servermq");
    if(response==0){
        printf("something went wrong with MQconnect\n");
    }
    else{
        //This loop continously scans planets given by the user
        //while(!(0)){
    printf("\nWrite to mailbox: ");
    scanf("%s", answer);


    MQwrite (mq_on_server, &answer);
    int c;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    //fflush(stdout);
        //}

    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Anyone have an idea why I am getting this kind of error? My friend has the exact same code and for him it is working.

Comment: How can `(mq== -1)` be true after `while(mq==-1)`?

Comment: My bad. The code is not perfect yet, will go through it.

Comment: regarding: `int nrOfBytes = mq_send(mq, (const char)sendBuffer, 1024, 10);`  The second parameter should be a pointer, not a char array.  Suggest: `int nrOfBytes = mq_send(mq, (const char*)sendBuffer, 1024, 10);

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", answer);`  The variable `answer` is only 20 bytes, so very easy to overflow the array `answer[]`  To avoid that problem, use a 'max characters' modifier of 19.  (19 because `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input.  Suggest: `scanf("%19s", answer);`

Comment: regarding: `MQwrite (mq_on_server, &answer);`  in C, a bare reference to an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array,  so that `&` needs to be removed

Comment: WHY is the code trying to output 1024 bytes when the actual message is (at most) 19 bytes?

Comment: the posted code is missing the critical statement: `#include <mqueue.h>`

Comment: @user3629249 thank you for your comments. I will change my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to dereference the given pointer in `MQconnect`.

```
int MQconnect (mqd_t * mq, char * name)
{
    //printf("hello from MQconnect\n");
#if 0
    /* wrong part */
    do{
        mq=mq_open(name, O_WRONLY);  //O_RDONLY
    }while(mq==-1);

    if(mq== -1){
#else
    /* fixed code */
    do{
        *mq=mq_open(name, O_WRONLY);  //O_RDONLY
    }while(*mq==-1);

    if(*mq== -1){
#endif
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return 1;
    // Connects to an existing mailslot for writing Uses mq as reference pointer, so that you can     reach the handle from anywhere/
    // Should return 1 on success and 0 on fail*/
}
```

Comment: I got rid of the error "Bad file descriptor" after dereferencing but now I got a new error: Value of errno: 14
Error printed by perror: Bad address
Error: Bad address

Comment: and the return value of mq_send is still -1.

Comment: You are saying the the length of message is 1024 while passing buffer whose length is only 20 bytes. This looks bad.

Comment: Yeah I tried to change the char answer[20] to char answer[1024] but didnt solve it either. Any idea on how I can prevent this ?

Comment: Solved. I just missed to dereference (const char)sendBuffer. Changed to (const char) * senBuffer and worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @SaefJasem Please upvote (and accept) answers when they're useful.

Comment: @Gnoom I did an upvote but because I am new to stackoverflow it wont show up.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I'm still happy to see that green checkmark :)